# How to avoid a chrome caching search results by css selectors?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

Steps which cause the problem:

1. Search for some element in the page via Chrome Dev Tools using css selector — it has results.
2. Remove this element (in any way) (NOT CLOSING search by css selector panel).
   search again using the same selector — it has no results
3. Restore this element (in any way, e.g. ctrl+Z) (NOT CLOSING search by css selector panel again).
4. Search again using the same selector - it has **NO** results, **that's is issue**.
5. Reopen panel or adding/removing space to the selector or any other manipulation — it has results again.

The same behaviour observed in chromedriver. That's because test fails.

**The question:** How can I achive the correct search by css selectors using chromedriver?

Comment: If that is supposed to be a _question_, then “It is raining today” would be one as well.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in devtools/chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid it. But you can file a [bug report](https://crbug.com/new) so the team can triage the problem and resolve it.